# Use dockerfile to build npm project

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I have Dockerfile like:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

USER node

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN npm run build
```

I need compiled files on my local drive not in docker container.
`VOLUME` looks like I need I think, but dunno how to do it, to make the build and share those build files.

can someone help me ? thanks!

Comment: Why don't you run `npm run build` on your project folder locally?

Comment: For some reason ( maybe because of graalVM ) build on my machine takes for ever, and in dockerfile just a few secs :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `npm run build` in your Dockerfile produces a `build` directory, you can get  it locally using a volume indeed

```
docker build -t <yourcontainername> .
docker run \
    -v ${PWD}/build:/home/node/app/build \
    -it <yourcontainername>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target
```